# Can a simple person (Muslim) pass Sirat bridge at the speed of lightening?

Tags: hereafter

Can a simple person (Muslim) pass Sirat bridge at the speed of lightening?

**What does he/she have to do in his/her life?**

Or is it only prophets who pass the bridge that fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small portion of [Sahih Muslim 183](https://sunnah.com/muslim:183a):

> It was asked: Messenger of Allah, what is this bridge? He said: The void in which one Is likely to slip. There would be hooks, tongs, spits like the thorn that is found in Najd and is known as Sa'dan. **The believers** would then pass over within the twinkling of an eye, like lightning, like wind, like a bird, like the finest horses and camels. Some will escape and be safe, some will be lacerated and let go, and some will be pushed into the fire of Hell till the believers will find rescue from the Fire.

In the above hadith that the Prophet specified the speeds, he was speaking in general about the believers, not specifying just the Prophets. So yes, the simplest Muslim has the potential to reach a level that allows him to pass over very quickly.

> "What does he/she have to do in his/her life?"

Not only should the Muslim do good deeds and repent, but rather he/she should continuously hasten to more good deeds. SubhanAllah, makes sense that our hastening towards good in the Dunya is a factor that determines how hastily we cross the bridge in the Akhirah.

> Qur'an 2:148 ولكلّ وجهة هو موليها فاستبقوا الخيرات أين ما تكونوا يأت بكم الله جميعا إن الله على كل شيء قدير  (For each [religious following] is a direction toward which it faces. So **race to [all that is] good**. Wherever you may be, Allah will bring you forth [for judgement] all together. Indeed, Allah is over all things competent.)

Read also: ["The ways in which people will pass over the siraat will vary according to their deeds"](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/235464/the-ways-in-which-people-will-pass-over-the-siraat-will-vary-according-to-their-deeds).

Comment: Very scary, very very scary actually. I am scared to death!!! :). Jazakallahu Hayrun!